# How to bind *.AAR file in Xamarin with Visual Studio/Xamarin Studio

Tags: c#, java, xamarin.android, xamarin

I want to bind HoloEverywhere in Xamarin. The HoloEverywhere binary is a .aar file. It seems that if I mark it as InputJar, nothing happens in the Java Library binding project. So is there a way to make it work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To bind to an `.aar`, the build action must be `LibraryProjectZip`.

http://docs.xamarin.com/releases/android/xamarin.android_4/xamarin.android_4.7/#Xamarin.Android_4.7.10.