# Xamarin Android Binding ReferenceJar equivalent in aar?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, aar

I trying to bind an .aar library that depends on other .aar library. In the ".jar" world, I would set the library I want to create the binding as "InputJar" and the dependencies as "ReferenceJar".

In ".aar", the equivalent for "InputJar" is "LibraryProjectZip", but... what would be the equivalent for "ReferenceJar"? EmbeddedNativeLibrary? Or "LibraryProjectProperties"?

Thanks!

Comment: If this helps.... what I did to solve my problem was open the .aar file with a zip program, extract the "classes.jar" and rename it to the same .aar name . Following these steps for each .aar library, I could create the binding in the same way the documentation says (with .jar instead of .aar.

Hope Xamarin adds support for linked .aar soon :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to create two binding projects, one for your .aar library (Library1) and another one for your .aar dependency (Library2). Please note that both .aar binding projects require `buildAction` set to `LibraryProjectZip`. Afterwards just add Library2 as a dependency as Library1. In the Xamarin world that means add the binding project of Library2 as a reference to the Library1 binding project.

Jar dependencies can be added directly thru `BuildAction = ReferenceJar`.

Other common dependencies can be added via the nuget package manager.

Answer (score -2):

The answer seems to be explain [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23318859/how-to-bind-aar-file-in-xamarin-with-visual-studio-xamarin-studio), the settings describe inside works for me.

the `.aar` file require a build action set to `LibraryProjectZip`

Comment: Not what I asked. In my original question I said that I know that I have to set the build action to LibraryProjectFile. The question is "what is the equivalent of "ReferenceJar"?